# Select schema and table dynamically according to a parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a group of tables that store the zip codes of different countries. Each table (called postal_codes) of a country is in a different schema, for example: zone_us, zone_uk, zone_fr, etc. I have a table in the public schema that stores the IDs of all zip codes along with the country code (us, uk, fr, ...). When querying the ID of a postal code (public.postal_codes), the query must also return the record of its postal code within the schema linked to the country of origin.

For example:

table public.postal_codes

```
id  country  zone_code_id
1   us       2
2   uk       4
3   uk       2
4   fr       9
```

table zone_us.postal_codes

```
id   code      address
2    3454355   Example Street X
```

table zone_uk.postal_codes

```
id   code      address
2    9845654   Example Street X
4    7845654   Example Street Z
```

table zone_fr.postal_codes

```
id   code      address
9    9456546   Example Street X
```

The query should check if there is a table for the zone (zone_[country_code].postal_codes), if yes, then return the corresponding line, if not, make the query in a default zone (zone_default.postal_codes).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That's a horrible design. You should store all postal codes in a single table together with a column denoting the country.

Comment: I understand your argument, but some countries has a specific addressing format. I don't consider it as simple to fit all formats into the same table with defined columns and sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function to solve my problem, but I don't know if it's the most efficient way. If anyone has a better suggestion.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_zone_postal_code("country_code" VARCHAR, "code_id" INT4) RETURNS SETOF RECORD
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
   schema_name varchar := 'zone_br';
BEGIN 
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE  table_schema = 'zone_' || country_code and table_name = 'postal_codes') THEN
        schema_name := 'zone_' || country_code;
    END IF;
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE FORMAT('SELECT code FROM %I.postal_codes WHERE id = %s', schema_name, code_id);
END 
$BODY$;
```